# Workflow create list when item is added in calendar

Tags: sharepoint-designer, list, workflow, web-services, calendar

I'm trying to achieve the following thing:
I have a calendar "Events". When creating an event, i. e. "Event A" I want a workflow to start, which creates a list "Attendees for Event A". Also in one column there should then be a link to that attendees list. So for every event a seperate list should be created and linked.

I think I read that this is achievable with calling a web service?

Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have to create a new list with each event?  You could instead populate a second list with all attendees, regardless of event, but index each new attendee item with the corresponding event name and ID.  This would allow you to filter and sort attendees by event in one list, without creating multiple lists.  To create a new list item when an event is created, use a Designer list workflow that fires on item create.  Attach the workflow to an existing calendar.  Use the "Create new list item" to populate the attendee information in another existing list.  Add another action to copy the source event's ID and Title to the new item's Title field or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a list using web services it is possible through SharePoint Designer, but only if you have at least the 2013 version and a Server or Enterprise version. [Here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-create-a-list-using-http-web-service-in-sharepoint-designer-2013-workflow/) you can see how. Besides, in the tutorial, it is explained how to create the column in the list. Creating a column list as a step through the workflow is not possible.

However, I do not recommend that way. You could code an **Item Adding Event Receiver**, so, when an item is created in the *Event* calendar, that receiver will fire, and it will create a list with the columns and data you want to fill in. [Here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/5b1f04/creating-simple-event-receiver-in-sharepoint-2013/) you can find how to create and deploy an Event Receiver.

IMHO, this is not the most effective way to pose this requirement. @JennyHersko's approach is more logical.